# NotificationCenter: BAD_ACCESS when Notification postet

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access, nsnotificationcenter

I have an app with 3 viewcontrollers that are pushed on a navigation controller stack.

`(A) -> (B) -> (C)`

`(A)` registers for notifications in `viewWillAppear`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DATA_CHANGED"), object: nil)
```

and `(A`) deregisters in `viewWillDisappear`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DATA_CHANGED"), object: nil)
```

Additionally `(A)` deregisters in `deinit()` but this is never called.

Now `(B)` is pushed on stack and registers /deregisters for the same event like `(A)`.

Now `(C)` is pushed on stack that triggers a computation and pops back to `(B)`. Some time later while `(B)` is presented the computation is finished and a Notification is fired:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "DATA_CHANGED"), object: nil)
```

But this results in an

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I'm sure that the notification is the problem because i misspelled the notification name and then no crash occurred. Also `(A)` and `(B)` are still not deallocated as the are living on the stack. I could not find any Zombie in Profiler.

Any idea what might be the problem?

I'm using XCode 9beta6 and Swift 4.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the stack trace.

Comment: There is no stack trace. I only get EXC_BAD_ACCESS as a red line.

Comment: Set the exception breakpoint to get the affected line, the actual exception reason and the stack trace. Most likely the signature of the selector is wrong.

Comment: Yes - the selectors name was wrong... If you write an answer to check the selectors name I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I just spent about 4 hours fixing this in my own code. Here is what my problem was:

The function I specified in my selector had an optional parameter with a default value of nil. My selector then looked just like yours - no parameter list. However, when I was firing a notification, I was getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I was trying to call a parent's function with my selector in relation to the child class I was registering the notification on. I had to make a helper function on the child class and call the parent's function.

If you have an optional parameter in reload and/or reload is a function in a parent class, try making a helper function which calls reload and make your selector point to that.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I had almost similar case. I had extra parameter in function I specified in selector.

Answer (score 1):

You are registering notification with name "BACKEND_DATA_CHANGED" and deregistering "DATA_CHANGED".They are different notifications.

Comment: sorry - I simplified the example and made an error there. Now it is correct

Comment: Are you getting same error even when names are correct?